# Keeping more history in GNU screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When scrolling up through the history of `screen` session with `ctrl+a ESC` (the output in terminal), it only goes back a small number of lines.

How do I configure `screen` to keep (much) longer history? I'd like to configure this globally and permanently, not per session.

Comment: This is going to depend on your window manager.  Are you using Gnome? KDE?

Comment: @ScottWilson can you elaborate about the relation with the other window managers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
defscrollback <numberOfLines>
```

to your $HOME/.screenrc file or to the more global /etc/screenrc

See the CUSTOMIZATION section of the screen manual page for more details about using this command, those files, and the files precedence.

Ubuntu screen's man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/screen.1.html

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL` + `A` then type: `scrollback 1000000` for 1 million lines. It’ll use about 16 GB at full utilization.